# Implement Amazon Pay by using React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I implement Amazon Pay by using React Native.
But I have no idea How can I implement Amazon pay by React Native.
I tried [amazon-pay-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-pay-react) but I had got error[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0904.png)

Could you let me teach how to implement amazon pay by React Native.

thank you best regards.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import AmazonPay from 'amazon-pay-react';
 

export default class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <AmazonPay
        clientId='your-cliendId'
        sellerId='your-sellerId'
        agreementType={'BillingAgreement'}
        scope='profile payments:widget'
        btnType='PwA'
        btnColor='Gold'
        btnSize='medium'
        onConsentChange={(hasConsent) => ...handle}
        handleBillingAgreementId={(billingAgreementId) => ...handle}
       billingAgreementId={this.state.billingAgreementId}
        useAmazonAddressBook={true}
/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: "I implement Amazon Pay by using React Native. But I have no idea How can I implement Amazon pay by React Native" Is this not just contradictory.

Comment: Seems like `amazon-pay-react` is for regular webpages and not React Native which does _not_ run in a regular webpage.

Comment: https://medium.com/@avremelk/amazonpay-react-js-f2c84931f82b - You can follow this along. Its written well. even though its for react but you can make it work for react-native too

Comment: @Derek. Yes it doesn't work on React Native. window.document only work on React.

Comment: @Anas M.I Thanks a lot I will try it soon.

Comment: @Yuki Did you implement it?